# When using multiple Docker Compose config files in CLI, do they need specifying with all command runs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using Docker Compose with multiple configuration files (e.g., [to allow multiple environments to share a common configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/)), I can't figure out if all commands in the CLI need to have all config files mentioned.

For example, I have *docker.compose.yml* and *docker.compose.dev.yml*, and I launch my dev environment as such:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```

If I want to run a command on a service, I can use:

```
docker-compose web ls
```

Or I can use:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml run ls
```

Both commands work, so I wasn't sure if the configuration files get associated with the containers once they're built.

Comment: While I believe I found my answer (as posted below), I am still curious if I'm using this Compose "extending" feature as the Compose developers intended. Thoughts?

Comment: Regarding my concern of using Compose's extend feature correctly, there is an alternative setup where the `extends` keyword is used to link between Compose config files. As I note in my answer below, Rackspace has a great example of this: https://github.com/rackerlabs/guestbook

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, if you want the overriding configuration file to be applied when the docker-compose CLI command is run, **you need to specify all configuration files.**

This may not always be apparent: the examples given in the question (`docker-compose web ls` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml run ls`) ***may*** both run without an error (really depends on what command you're running), **but all settings in *docker-compose.dev.yml* will not be applied.**

Here's an example of when this can be a problem:

1. Assume *docker-compose.yml* has all settings defaulted to a production environment where *docker-compose.dev.yml* sets these to some safe development setup **(this is a horrible environment setup, but maybe other setups will have a similar problem)**
2. Assume web is a Django app that uses django-storages to store static files on a CDN;
3. When running `docker-compose run web python manage.py collectstatic`, files would be uploaded to the production address, thus possibly causing unexpected production changes.

With all this in mind, I recommend renaming *docker-compose.yml* to something like *docker-compose.base.yml*, thus running `docker-compose run web python manage.py collectstatic` would error about *docker-compose.yml* being missing.

**Note of alternative setup:** an alternative setup for the multiple environments, as described on the referenced Compose documentation, is to use the `extends` keyword in the docker files. Rackspace developed an sample project, [available on Github](https://github.com/rackerlabs/guestbook), that provides a great example of using this feature.